# Python: Newspaper Module - Extract text with html tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-newspaper

I made a code:

```
from newspaper import Article
url = 'http://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-e-indices/noticia/7345670/dow-jones-tem-nova-derrocada-puxa-ibovespa-para-segunda-semana'
a = Article(url, language='pt')
a.download()
a.parse()
print(a.text)
```

But I need the text with html tag, for example, I need the img tag inside text.

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked one year ago but somebody may find this question via Google.

You can get the images and other html inside the article text with "a.article_html".

```
from newspaper import Article

a = Article('https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/25/us/politics/joe-biden-anita-hill.html', 
    keep_article_html=True, 
    language='en')
a.download()
a.parse()

print(a.html) # This article's unchanged and raw HTML
print(a.article_html) # The HTML of this article's main node
```

Remember the parameter "keep_article_html=True"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html via `html` member.

```
from newspaper import Article
url = 'http://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/acoes-e-indices/noticia/7345670/dow-jones-tem-nova-derrocada-puxa-ibovespa-para-segunda-semana'
a = Article(url, language='pt')
a.download()
a.parse()
print(a.text)

html = a.html
print(html)
```